# woocommerce shortcode with stock quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock

I would like a shortcode like the following example that shows the stock of the products:

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" category="pantalones" cat_operator="IN"]
```

I would need something like this:

```
[products limit="8" columns="4" category="pantalones" cat_operator="IN" showstock="yes"]
```

I found this code a few days ago, I found it here on stackoverflow, but now I don't remember the link, sorry.:

```
add_shortcode( 'minimum_stock', 'minimum_stock_shortcode' );

function minimum_stock_shortcode( $atts ) {

global $woocommerce_loop;

// Attributes 
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
            'limit'         => '40',
            'columns'       => '5',
            'orderby'       => 'title',
            'order'         => 'asc',
            'category'      => '',
            'cat_operator'  => 'IN',
            'stock'         => '',
            ),
            $atts, 'minimum_stock'
        );

        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'posts_per_page'        => $atts['limit'],
            'orderby'               => $atts['orderby'],
            'order'                 => $atts['order'],
            'meta_query'            => array(
                array(
                    'key'           => '_stock',
                    'value'         => $atts['stock'],
                    'compare'       => '>='
                )
            ),
            'tax_query'             => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                    'field'         => 'slug',
                    'terms'         => $atts['category'],
                )   
            )
        );


ob_start();

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>     

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

        <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

<?php endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

return '<div class="woocommerce">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

This code works perfect, but not show stock in homepage

I think the solution is not to modify the shortcode, but to modify the template that it uses to visualize data, but I don't know how to do it, if someone knows where it is or how it's done, I deeply appreciate it

Very thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found, solution, thanks, very thanks

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'bbloomer_show_stock_shop', 10 );
  
function bbloomer_show_stock_shop() {
   global $product;
   echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );
}
```